# Increment movieClip name and addChild

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, for-loop

I am trying to use a for loop to increment the creation of a movieClip and adds the movie clip to the stage.

Something like this:

```
        for (var i:int = 0; i<6;i++){
        var ball + i:MovieClip = new Ball();
        addChild(ball + i);
        ball + i.x = 470;
        ball + i.y = 130;
        }
```

Am I going about this incorrectly?
I am getting the following error:

C:\PATH TO MY /ASFILE.as, Line 64   1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good way of doing this is by creating an `Array` containing the newly created balls.

```
var ball:Ball;
var arrayBalls:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int = 0; i<6;i++)
{
    ball = new Ball();
    addChild(ball);

    ball.x = 470;
    ball.y = 130;

    arrayBalls.push(ball);
}
```

You store a reference of every `ball` in the `arrayBalls` so you don't have to create a new var each time. By stating `ball = new Ball()` you're 'erasing' the previous stored value and simply create a new one. Later on you can loop through your `Array` and do whatever you like with it. Like so

```
var ball:Ball;
for (var i:int = 0; i < arrayBalls.length; i++) 
{
    ball = arrayBalls[i];
}
```

Or something like this

```
var ball:Ball = arrayBalls[3];
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, whats that?  :D

Do you want to increment the property name or the instance name?

For property name:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<6;i++)
{
    var ball:MovieClip = new Ball();
    ball.name = 'ball' + i;
    addChild(ball);
    ball.x = 470;
    ball.y = 130;
}
```

For instance name there is no need for that, you can store into an array like **rvmook** said.